# DTD define Number of occurrences of elements with mixed content

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

How we add constraints for child elements when Declaring mix content element in DTD?
This is my xml.

```
<!ELEMENT manager (contact)>
<!ATTLIST manager name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT contact (#PCDATA|office|mobile+|email*)*>
<!ELEMENT mob (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT office (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
```

When I wrote this I got a error which says **The mixed content model "contact" must end with ")*" when the types of child elements are constrained.**

Please help..

*The constraints for the contact element are, the office element must appears only one time, the mobile element must appears one or more times, the email element is optional.*

This is my what I want,

```
<contact>
            Contact Details:
            <email>sam@yahoo.com</email>
            <mob>077769768</mob>
            <office>036568879</office>
</contact>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content) can only be declared one way. You can't specify how many times an element can occur in a mixed content declaration.

Your declaration would have to look like this:

```
<!ELEMENT contact (#PCDATA|office|mobile|email)*>
```

> The constraints for the contact element are, the office element must
>   appears only one time, the mobile element must appears one or more
>   times, the email element is optional.

Your constraints don't sound like you need mixed content; maybe this will be enough:

```
<!ELEMENT contact (office,mobile+,email?)>
```

Comment: thank for your reply, I forgot to mention in constraints that there also should be parsed character data. I updated the question. This is what I want to validate.                          
              <contact>
   Contact Details:
   <email>sam@yahoo.com</email>
   <mob>077769768</mob>
   <office>036568879</office>
  </contact>

Answer (score 0):

The mixed content model can only specify the names of child elements that can occur. A child elements order or number of occurrences cannot be set. Having these limitations it is not recommended to use the mixed content model.